# Stuck On A CSS Challenge

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I'm stuck on a frontendmentor challenge specifically the stats preview card component.

I am trying to take the text that is in the div stats-div and move it below the h2's that ive given various classes.

this is my current set up.
[image: Currently Written]

and this is my code.

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
}

.card {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-style: hidden;
  height: 30vh;
  margin: 100px 75px 75px 75px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: lexend deca;
  margin: 100px 0 0 50px;
}

.insights {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

p {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  font-family: inter;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 175%;
  margin: 25px 0 0 50px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.right-image {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 42%;
}

.stats-div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0 0 50px;
}

.companies-number, .templates-number, .queries-number {
  margin: 0;
  width: 10%;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  font-family: lexend deca;
  flex: 1;
}

.stats {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="girls interacting with technology gleefully" class="right-image">
      <h1>Get <span class="insights">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>

      <p> Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer
        experience, and overall efficiency.</p>

      <div class="stats-div">
        <h2 class="companies-number">
          10k+</h2>

        <p class="stats">companies</p>
        <h2 class="templates-number">314</h2>
        <p class="stats">templates</p>
        <h2 class="queries-number">12m+</h2>
        <p class="stats">queries</p>
      </div>
      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
        Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

here is what the card is intended to look like:
[image: goal design]

I'm particularly interested if my code is properly being used. I'm very new to css (hence the beginner level challenge).

Comment: Please edit the post and include corresponding HTML code.

Comment: sorry about that! code added in!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each pair of `h2` and `p.stats` in an enclosing `div`

```css
.card {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.stats-div {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
}

.stats-div-item {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100%/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="stats-div">
    <div class="stats-div-item">
      <h2>10k+</h2>
      <p>companies</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-div-item">
      <h2>314</h2>
      <p>templates</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-div-item">
      <h2>12m+</h2>
      <p>queries</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the extra div in place, another way of doing this is with css grid.

```css
.card {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.stats-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="stats-div">
    <div>
      <h2>10k+</h2>
      <p>companies</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>314</h2>
      <p>templates</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>12m+</h2>
      <p>queries</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, this might be possible without altering the initial html by using css columns.

```css
.stats-div {
  columns: 3;
}

.stats-div>h2 {
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="stats-div">
  <h2>10k+</h2>
  <p>companies</p>
  <h2>314</h2>
  <p>templates</p>
  <h2>12m+</h2>
  <p>queries</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I was wracking my brain thinking it was a css issue when I just needed the divs separated out and let it fall into line by the default styling.